# Flyback Average Model

Tags: pwm, ltspice, model

I wanted to try the PWM switch model to make a bode plot from the transfer function of the flyback with fixed duty cycle in LTspice.

I had already a working transient model which give me the correct results regarding Vout 12 V but if I try to build up the model with the PWM switch I don't get meaningful results. With the transient result I wanted to check if I get first the correct output voltage with this circuit. At first I tried a static duty cycle here

- D=0.213
- Lp=616 µH
- Ls=4 µH
- ü=12.4
- fsw=65 kHz.

At 339 Vdc it should give me a output voltage of 12 V. I tested the XFRM1 model itself and it gives me the correct voltage ratio. The X1, PWM-VM circuit is saved as PWM-VM.asc file in the same folder:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

These files I get from here http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm

- PWM-VM.asc: https://pastecode.io/s/z0pcsacb
- PWM-VM.asy: https://pastecode.io/s/74sf5fec

What's wrong here, can someone help me here? The Ouput voltage on pin "p" of X1 is wrong but why?

Comment: Please post waveforms.

Comment: I added the waveforms. From the voltage levels, it looks really weired. The output voltage on pin "p" of X1 looks strange.

Comment: Is it switching at all? I have never used X1 or a pre-defined transformer model. Have you considered using a transistor or ideal switch and coupled inductors instead?

Comment: Your `Vfast` needs to be a switching waveform.  All you have is `AC 1` which is for `.ac` analysis only.  It doesn't work with `.tran`.  Edit `Vfast` to a `PULSE` waveform.

Comment: Did you use coupled inductors here? You have to use a dc transformer otherwise the dc operating point cannot be determined.